# Php mail not submitting and blank page displaying

Tags: php, html, ampps

I am using Ampps on Mac and trying to send an email using php from a contact form however I do not receive the mail and when the form is submitted it redirects me to the file page resulting in a blank display

my form :

```
<form action="email.php" method="post">
                <div class="col-md-6 w3_agileits_contact_left">
                    <span class="input input--akira">
                        <input class="input__field input__field--akira" type="text" id="input-22" name="Name" placeholder="" required="" />
                        <label class="input__label input__label--akira" for="input-22">
                            <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--akira">Your name</span>
                        </label>
                    </span>
                    <span class="input input--akira">
                        <input class="input__field input__field--akira" type="email" id="input-23" name="Email" placeholder="" required="" />
                        <label class="input__label input__label--akira" for="input-23">
                            <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--akira">Your email</span>
                        </label>
                    </span>
                    <span class="input input--akira">
                        <input class="input__field input__field--akira" type="text" id="input-24" name="Subject" placeholder="" required="" />
                        <label class="input__label input__label--akira" for="input-24">
                            <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--akira">Your subject</span>
                        </label>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 w3_agileits_contact_right">
                    <div class="w3_agileits_contact_right1">
                                                <textarea name="Message" id="Message" placeholder="Your comment here..." required=""></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3_agileits_contact_right2">
                                                <input type="submit" value="Send">
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>




            </form>
```

my File :

```
$email = $_POST['Email'];
                                    $name = $_POST['Name'];
                                    $to = "lucvanrooyen@gmail.com";
                                    $subject = $_POST['Subject'];
                                    $userMessage =$_POST['Message'];
                                    $headers = "From: $email\n";
                                    $message = "$name has sent you the following message.\n

                                    Message: $userMessage";
                                    $user = "$email";
                                    $usersubject = "Thank You";
                                    $userheaders = "From: lucvanrooyen@gmail.com\n";
                                    $usermessage = "Thank you for your enquiry we will be in touch.";
                                     mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
                                     mail($user,$usersubject,$usermessage,$userheaders);
```

Comment: please share your code as text here for more help.

Comment: Run a `var_dump($_POST)` on your php script and you'll see that you don't have data such as `$_POST['input-22']`. Enable PHP errors to see why your mail() function is failing I guess.

Comment: @Generic There you go

Comment: @IsThisJavascript I changed it to the input items names and var dumped them the values are there but the mail isn't coming through still is it possible my Ampps local server ?

Answer (score -1):

The code you have shown is not enough to debug your problem.

If you are using the [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) method which is built into the standard library, read this answer to find out a few [troubleshooting steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail/24644450#24644450) you could follow.

If you are and are still finding it difficult to use, then you could consider using one of the PHP emailing solutions like -

- [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
- [SwiftMailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Please check your form tag. there is no opening tag for form

```
<form action="email.php" method="post">
```